# modal dialog resolve ignores passed property value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to transfer some modal properties like this

```
service.confirm = function(message, confirmProperties) {
        return $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/modal/alert/alert.tpl.html',
            controller: 'alertController as vm',
            size: 'md',
            resolve: {
                alertData: function() {
                    return {
                        message: message,
                        type: 'QUESTION',
                        customButtons: confirmProperties.button1 && confirmProperties.button2 ? [confirmProperties.button1, confirmProperties.button2] : undefined,
                        cancelButton: confirmProperties.cancelButton,
                        title: confirmProperties.title,
                        ignoreWhiteSpaces: confirmProperties.ignoreWhiteSpaces
                    }
                }
            },
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true
        });
    };
```

When calling my function, all properties are passed fine except 'ignoreWhiteSpaces' one... Even though I pass false, it 'comes out' as undefined. Why is that? I've spend over an hour on this trying to figure it out.

```
var confirmProperties = {
                    button1: 'Update Existing Contracts',
                    button2: 'No Update to Existing Contracts',
                    cancelButton: true,
                    title: 'Update Service on the Customers Existing Contracts',
                    ignoreWhiteSpace: false
                };
appState.confirm('This is the message.', confirmProperties);
```

[image]

Comment: Can u create a plunkr demo and let us know. Hard to guess if one of the property isnt working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. `ignoreWhiteSpace` instead of `ignoreWhiteSpaces`.
Change your code from:

```
var confirmProperties = {
                button1: 'Update Existing Contracts',
                button2: 'No Update to Existing Contracts',
                cancelButton: true,
                title: 'Update Service on the Customers Existing Contracts',
                ignoreWhiteSpace: false
            };
```

to

```
var confirmProperties = {
                button1: 'Update Existing Contracts',
                button2: 'No Update to Existing Contracts',
                cancelButton: true,
                title: 'Update Service on the Customers Existing Contracts',
                ignoreWhiteSpaces: false
            };
```